# progress bar running continue

Tags: android

I wrote a `game play screen` with a progress bar. I only want the progress bar to run for 4 seconds, but it doesn't stop.

I wrote a `MainActivity` class with a `gamelayout`. In this layout I want to add the `progress bar`.

Why does the progress bar keep running?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = null;
public int ROWS = 10;
public int COLS = 10;
public String a = "";
public String x = "";
public static int textSize;
public static int wordListTextSize;
public boolean gameFinish = false;
public Timer timer;
public Vector<Integer> coordinate_X1 = new Vector<Integer>();
public Vector<Integer> coordinate_Y1 = new Vector<Integer>();
public Vector<Integer> coordinate_X2 = new Vector<Integer>();
public Vector<Integer> coordinate_Y2 = new Vector<Integer>();
RelativeLayout winPopUp = null;
public int cellWidth = 0;
public int cellHeight = 0;
public TextView tv1;
public char[][] charArray;
public Vector<String> wordList;
public String[] tempWordList;
public RelativeLayout gameLayout;
//public RelativeLayout mainLayout;
public int colorCounter = 0;
public int noOfSelectedWords = 0;
public int totalNoOfWords = 0;

public int sec = 0;
public int hour = 0;
public int min = 0;
boolean gameStarted = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);



    // here is a relative layout , we get id of this layout and  add progress bar 
  //  to this reletive layout 

    final RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    mainLayout.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loading, mainLayout);
            ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,
                    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        new DrawGame().execute(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });//here is code of add progress bar how we stop progress bar which is running 
                  //continue

}

public void initPlay() {
    ROWS = ScreenConstants.ROWS;
    cellWidth = cellHeight = (((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutBg))
            .getHeight() * 98 / 100) / ROWS;
    System.out.println("Height "
            + findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutBg).getHeight());
    cellHeight = cellHeight - cellHeight / ROWS;
    cellWidth = 200;
    COLS = ScreenConstants.SCREENWIDTH / cellWidth;
    COLS = 10;
    gamePlay();
}

public void gamePlay() {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.getGame(ROWS, COLS, this, ScreenConstants.MAX_LENGTH);
    gameLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayoutBg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            280, 300);
    rlparams.topMargin = 30;
    tv1 = new TextView(this);
    // tv1.setLayoutParams(rlparams);
    tv1.setId(1);

    charArray = new char[ROWS][COLS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            charArray[i][j] = game.charArray[index];
            x = x + "  " + charArray[i][j];
            tv1.setText(x);
            tv1.setTextSize(20);
            // tv1.setText(""+charArray[i][j]);
            Log.d(TAG, "VALUE OF TEXT BOX " + tv1);
            gameLayout.removeAllViews();
            gameLayout.addView(tv1, rlparams);
            index++;
        }
    }

    wordList = game.wordList;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordListLayoutBg1);

    tempWordList = Utility.getStringArray(wordList);
    for (int i = 0; i < tempWordList.length; i++) {

        a = a + "   " + tempWordList[i];
    }
    tv.setText(a);
    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    // }
    totalNoOfWords = wordList.size();
    noOfSelectedWords = 0;

}


  private class DrawGame extends AsyncTask<MainActivity, Void, Boolean> {

  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        initPlay();
    }


@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    //initPlay();

    }


@Override protected Boolean doInBackground(MainActivity... obj)
{

    //initPlay();
    try {
        publishProgress();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


      return true;
  }
  }
```

Comment: When posting for help, posting your code is excellent, but even better is first trimming it of everything that is unrelated to the help you're seeking. The less noise you provide, the easier it is for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `R.id.progressBar1` is the progress bar you want to deal with, when you're ready to proceed, simply:

```
ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
spenner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `onPreExecute` for showing `ProgressBar`  and dismiss it inside `onPostExecute` Change your `AsyncTask` as :

```
 private class DrawGame extends AsyncTask<MainActivity, Void, Boolean> {
 ProgressBar spinner;
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Show Progress Bar here...
          spinner = (ProgressBar)MainActivity.this. 
                                   findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,
                    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

          spinner.setVisibality(0); //<<< make  Visible here
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         spinner.setVisibility(8);  //<<< make in-Visible here
    //initPlay();

    }
//your code here...
```